# Como selecionar apenas uma opção do Select?

Tags: javascript

como eu faço para selecionar/alterar somente a opção Loja 3 do meu select? Eu preciso que, ao clicar em Loja 3 ele faça alguma ação, como alterar cor, ou adicionar algum efeito em js.

```js
$(function() {
        $('.filtro-compre').change(function(){
           $('.blocos').hide()
            $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

```css
<style type="text/css">


.modelo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.modelo div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 30px
}

.varejo {
    background-color: red
}

.viagens {
    background-color: yellow
}

.servicos {
    background-color: gray
}
.blocos {
    display: none
}
</style>
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-master">

<div class="form-group"><select class="filtro-compre" id="list-lugar" name="unidade"><option disabled="true" selected="true" value="0">Ordenar por</option><option name="varejo" value="varejo">Loja 1</option><option name="servicos" value="servicos">Loja 2</option><option name="viagens" value="viagens">Loja 3</option></select></div>
</div>

<div class="modelo">
<div class="varejo blocos"></div>
<div class="servicos blocos"></div>
<div class="viagens blocos"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Quer fazer efeito na option "Loja 3"?

Comment: exatamente, como eu faço?

Comment: Vc pega o valor da option, compara no `$('.filtro-compre').change(function(){`  e faz o que quiser se o valor for igual o da option: `if($(this).val() == "viagens"){ // faz alguma coisa }`

Comment: Valeu cara, era isso mesmo, muito obrigado.